# Metal API clips all primitives?

Tags: metal

I am trying to port my simple app from D3D12 to Metal and I am stuck at rendering a simple triangle.

The window does not show any primitives; only the clear color is visible.

Debugging my application, I noticed, that all primitives are clipped (Performance > Primitives > Primitives Clipped: 100%). I fail to understand why this happens, as these are my coordinates:

```c
struct vertex { float x, y, z; };
static const struct vertex vertices[] =
{
    { 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f },
    { 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f },
    { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f }
};
```

What I have tried so far:

- Explicitly setting the viewport `{0, 0, 800, 600, 0, 1}`.
- Explicitly setting scissors `{0, 0, 800, 600}`.
- Setting the cull mode to `MTLCullModeNone`.
- Setting the fill mode to `MTLTriangleFillModeFill`.
- Changing the winding order.
- Altering the vertex input layout; but I am confident, that mine matches the input.

Are there any pitfalls of Metal that I am missing? (i.e. setting the sample mask like in D3D12?)

My pipeline for reference:

```
    MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor* descriptor = [MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor new];
    descriptor.vertexFunction   = desc->vertex->handle;
    descriptor.fragmentFunction = desc->pixel->handle;
    descriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm;
    
    MTLVertexDescriptor* vs = descriptor.vertexDescriptor;
    vs.attributes[0].format = MTLVertexFormatFloat3;
    vs.attributes[0].offset = 0;
    vs.attributes[0].bufferIndex = 0;
    
    vs.layouts[0].stride        = sizeof(float) * 3;
    vs.layouts[0].stepFunction  = MTLVertexStepFunctionPerVertex;
    vs.layouts[0].stepRate      = 1;
```

Note, that I am NOT using `MTKView`.

The following is my shader used:

```
struct Out 
{
    float4 pos [[position]];
};

vertex Out vertexShader(
    const device float3* vertices [[buffer(0)]],
    unsigned int idx [[vertex_id]]
) {
    Out out;
    out.pos = float4(vertices[idx], 1.0);
    return out;
}


fragment float4 fragmentShader(Out in [[stage_in]])
{
    // TODO: Write fragment shader
    return float4(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

---

EDIT:
I made following changes and my triangle is finally being rendered:

```c
struct vertex { float x, y, z, w; };
static const struct vertex vertices[] =
{
    { 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.f },
    { 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.f},
    { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.f }
};

// Vertex Descriptor
    MTLVertexDescriptor* vs = descriptor.vertexDescriptor;
    vs.attributes[0].format = MTLVertexFormatFloat4;
    vs.attributes[0].offset = 0;
    vs.attributes[0].bufferIndex = 0;
    
    vs.layouts[0].stride        = sizeof(float) * 4;
    vs.layouts[0].stepFunction  = MTLVertexStepFunctionPerVertex;
    vs.layouts[0].stepRate      = 1;
```

Shader:

```
struct Out 
{
    float4 pos [[position]];
};

vertex Out vertexShader(
    const device float4* vertices [[buffer(0)]],
    unsigned int idx [[vertex_id]]
) {
    Out out;
    out.pos = vertices[idx];
    return out;
}


fragment float4 fragmentShader(Out in [[stage_in]])
{
    // TODO: Write fragment shader
    return float4(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

I don't understand why my application fails, when using 3D vectors instead of 4D ones. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float3` in Metal Shading Language has the same size/alignment as `float4`, i.e. 16 bytes. I think your original code would have worked using `packed_float3` (12 bytes) in the vertex shader.